# "plugin invalidated" error in iOS keyboard app

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard

i am getting a pretty generic error in my debugger when using the simulator in xCode. 
plugin com.XXX.XXX.Shortcut-Keyboard invalidated

this just started occurring yesterday and i don't believe i changed anything. since the error started i had just added a few more outlets and actions. i did try something in the code which changed the first responder on a text field, but i have since removed that code and recompiled. It seems maybe this caused an issue? Now when i cycle thru the keyboards, when it gets to mine i get a few second pause and then this error. in debugging the code, it never seems to hit my viedDidLoad override in my keyboard view controler. So something i did must have changed it.

What would cause something like this to occur? I'm at a loss! Im using Xcode 6.3.1 with a target of 8.3 on an iPad. Any help would be appreciated as this is holding up my development.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: also, i checked and made sure i gave my keyboard full access. not i am also getting a "plugin interrupted" message before the invalidated one.

Comment: well, the only way i could resolve this was to create a new project from scratch. Thats pretty frustrating, but it did resolve my issue.

Comment: I can second this annoying issue :/

Answer (score -3):

start a new project and copy and paste the code resolved this issue